# Getting accelerometer values from phone, best approach?

Tags: android, python

I'm very new to python and I want to make some application that allows me to use the accelerometer values I get from my phone in windows. 
With SL4A (python for android) I created client and server scripts to read the values from the accelerometer and send them to the server (running on pc) through a socket.

This is my server code (windows pc):

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 5000))
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print buf
```

and this my client code (android phone):

```
import android, socket, time

droid = android.Android()

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('192.168.2.6', 5000))

def readAcc():
    dt = 100
    endTime = 300
    timeSensed = 0
    droid.startSensingTimed(2,dt)
    while timeSensed <= endTime:
        senout = droid.sensorsReadAccelerometer().result
        time.sleep(dt/1000.0)
        timeSensed+=dt

    print senout
    clientsocket.send(str(senout).strip('[]'))


readAcc()

droid.stopSensing()
```

Output example:

```
1.8659877, 8.8259849999999993, 3.5412905000000001
```

This works fine if I want to read the values once, but I was wondering how I would go from here, I want to be able to use the values for controlling games and other applications.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to first experiment with different motions of the device (say, a fast upward motion), gather the output values, and then simply trigger events (or whatever you need to trigger in a game) based on a specfic range of accelerometer values (similar movements should have similar value ranges).

Comment: I'm not that far actually, see I need a constantly updated variable but putting 'readAcc()' in a loop with the 'send' command still gives me only one variable. So far I've only been able to send one string without restarting the script.

Comment: After some more testing I think the problem is that I can run clientsocket.send() only once after a connection has been established.